# SQLite: Update: add 1 to previous value

Tags: android, sqlite

I am building an app on Android. And what I am trying to do is add 1 to the previous value in the database.

The value of the column score is 200 in the database.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
int resultRows = 0;
values = new ContentValues(1);
values.put(DBContract.Countries.SCORE, DBContract.Countries.SCORE + " + 1");
resultRows = db.update(DBContract.Countries.TABLE_NAME, values, DBContract.Countries.ISO + " = ?", selectionArgs);
```

The actual output is `SCORE + 1` instead of 201. So it is taking it as a `String` instead of adding it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ContentValues` to provide literal values only.

For SQL expressions, use raw SQL with `execSQL()`:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + DBContract.Countries.TABLE_NAME + " SET " +
    DBContract.Countries.SCORE + "=" + DBContract.Countries.SCORE + " + 1 " +
    "WHERE " + DBContract.Countries.ISO + " = ?", selectionArgs);
```